# How to test events on the root element of component in vue 2?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I'm writing unit tests for the following component:

```html
<template>
  <sub-component
     @foo="bar"
  />
</template>
<script>
import SubComponent from './SubComponent';

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  components: { SubComponent },
  methods: {
    bar(payload) {
       this.$emit('baz', ...payload);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And the test would be:

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import _ from 'lodash';
import MyComponent from '../../components/MyComponent';

describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent);
  });

  it('should emit baz on subcomponent foo', () => {
    const subComp = wrapper.find('sub-component-stub');
    expect(subComp.exists()).toBe(true);          // passes

    subComp.vm.$emit('foo');

    return wrapper.vm.$nextTick().then(() => {
      expect(wrapper.emitted().baz).toBeTruthy(); // does not pass;

      // upon logging: 
      console.log(_.isEqual(wrapper, subComp));   // => true 
    })
  })
})
```

The example is oversimplified, but the principle here is I want a reusable `<sub-component>` (a modal) and various functional wrappers around it (related to one particular task the modal type performs) which map additional functionality. I don't want the functionality in the parent components, as it would violate DRY - i'd have to place it in each component containing a particular type of modal.

This would work fine if `<sub-component>` was not the direct child of `<template>`. Somehow, it appears `wrapper` and `subComp` are hosted on the same element.

How should this be tested properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possibility it's to find your element in the dom and check the emitted value of your root component.

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue'
import SubComponent from './SubComponent.vue'

describe('MyComponent', () => {    

  it('should emit baz on subcomponent foo', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent)
    const subComponent = wrapper.find(SubComponent)

    expect(subComponent.exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.emitted('baz')).toBeUndefined()

    subComponent.vm.$emit('foo', ['hello'])
    expect(wrapper.emitted('baz')[0]).toEqual(['hello'])
    // or expect(wrapper).toEmit('baz', 'hello') cf. below for toEmit
  })

})
```

If you want a custom matcher for Jest:

```
toEmit(received, eventName, data) {
  if (data) {
    expect(received.emitted()[eventName][0]).toEqual([data])
  } else {
    expect(received.emitted()[eventName][0]).toEqual([])
  }
  return { pass: true }
}
```

Comment: `wrapper.find(SubComponent)` would error in my test, as `SubComponent` is undefined: it's not imported. I'm not `mount`-ing, I'm `shallowMount`-ing, which makes all sub-components stubs. As you might notice in the question, I'm finding the subcomponent correctly (for shallowMount). Yet, because the sub-component is also the root element of the component (as it's the one and only child of `<template>`) the normal `$emit('foo', payload)` doesn't work as it would if it was nested deeper: (i.e.: `<template><div><sub-component/></div></template>` - this works fine).

Comment: Assuming I import SubComponent and declare it in `stubs` property of wrapper, your solution has the same problem as the code in my question. wrapper's `bar()` function doesn't get called unless a wrapper for `SubComponent` is created first, using `createWrapper()`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I update my answer. With the spread on `payload` I need to have an array for args of the emit in the test: `subComponent.vm.$emit('foo', ['hello'])`. For me the code in the answer works well. Let me know

Comment: You're correct, it works if I import SubComponent and find it.

Answer (score 0):

When the child is the root, the selector will `wrapper.find(SubComponent)` will refer to the root component,
so you should go with `$children[0]`

```js
// subComponent here is the root which is actually MyComponent
const subComponent = wrapper.find(SubComponent); 
// subComponent.vm.$children[0] is the actual SubComponent
subComponent.vm.$children[0].$emit('foo', ['hello'])
```